# Elixir rename imported function to alias

Tags: elixir

Let's say I am testing a function belonging to Utils module like this

```
defmodule Test do
  alias Module.Utils

  test "test 1" do
    Utils.some_function?(...)
  end

  test "test 2" do
    Utils.some_function?(...)
  end
end
```

Can I refactor or simplify that function into something like:

```
import Utils.some_function as test_func()
```

So I dont have to write module name and simplify function name

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot rename a function while importing it.

You can use `defdelegate` to create a local function that calls another module's function like this:

```
defmodule A do
  def just_add_these_two_numbers(a, b), do: a + b
end

defmodule B do
  defdelegate add(a, b), to: A, as: :just_add_these_two_numbers
  # `add/2` is now the same as `A.just_add_these_two_numbers/2`.

  def test do
    IO.inspect add(1, 2) == 3
  end
end

B.test #=> true
```

Although you might as well just do this instead (it's even shorter):

```
def add(a, b), do: A.just_add_these_two_numbers(a, b)
```

Comment: Hi, if you know the parameter a is alway the same, can you define it within the defdelegate and then just add diferents "b" parameter in the rest of the tests?

Comment: Nope, `defdelegate` doesn't allow this. Even if it did, it'd be much shorter to just do `def add5(b), do: A.just_add_these_two_numbers(5, b)` and use that. This way you can also make the new function private by doing `defp`.

Comment: thanks, and can you declare that number 5 (5, b) as a variable in a line before the def add(a, b), do: A.just_add_these_two_numbers(a, b)? or the inner scope of add method wont see it?

Comment: I am trying to use a variable to make it look cleaner but it looks like doesnt recognice that variable

Comment: You can use module attributes. Add `@a 5` before `def` (note: no `=` after `@a`) and then use `@a` inside.

Comment: Sweet! thanks so much, you help me with a lof of elixir questions